# py2exe: how to generate .exe for application with GUI in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, py2exe

I want to generate for Windows platform the executable file of my Python GUI application.
  - I'm using two .py OO scripts
- The first script (processcls.py) contains this header:

```
from lxml import html
from urllib import urlopen
import os, re, sys, time
```

- The second script contains this header:

```
from processcls import *
from Tkinter import *
import Queue, threading, tkFileDialog, ttk, tkMessageBox, win32clipboard
```

- And this is my py2exe script. The problem is that I can't see any GUI created. So I don't clear know where is my mistake in the code.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    name='MyApplic',
    author='amazon',
    author_email='lepetit@sk.com',
    windows=[
        {
            'script':"init.py",
            'uac_info': "requireAdministrator","icon_resources": [(1, "favicon.ico")]
        }
    ], 
    options=
        {
            'py2exe':{
                'includes': ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'gzip', 'processcls'],
                'packages': ['lxml', 'urllib', 'Tkinter'],
                'bundle_files': 1,
                'compressed'  : True
        }
    },
    zipfile = None
)
```

Any suggestions?
I'm using Tkinter as a GUI gramework and Python 2.7

Thanks
Migrome

Comment: There are several other questions on using tkinter with py2exe.  Have you checked any of them?

Also although this doesn't answer your question I would recommend trying out [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) instead.  py2exe is no longer actively maintained and PyInstaller, its spiritual successor, is a little easier to use IMO.

Comment: Thanks. In fact there are some other questions about Tkinter but not with Tkinter+Py2exe, not specifically about the problem I have. Let me try PyInstaller and I will comment.

Comment: @Iguananaut - Py2exe is most definitely still maintained.  Thomas Heller deals with it over at SourceForge, and I know for a fact that an update is in the works that will include (among other things) support for bundle_files on 64-bit installs.

Comment: @MigRome - Also worth noting - pyinstaller uses 2-pass execution (extract to temp folder, run extracted program, clean up temp folder) for every launch of your program.  Depending on what your program does and whether it will be run repeatedly, that can cause _severe_ disk overhead.

Comment: I've read that `bundle_files 1` isn't supported on amd64 if that applies.

Comment: When you run `python setup.py py2exe` are there any errors?

Comment: @g.d.d.c My mistake--I was going by the fact that the py2exe website is currently down, and the last release seems to be from 2008, so by any cursory inspection it doesn't appear very active.  I've personally found PyInstaller a bit easier to deal with.  As for how PyInstaller handles execution that depends on what options are used when running it.

Comment: @martineau - `bundle_files 3` was the only supported value, but recent improvements on the development branch have addressed that.  I can vouch for the latest source supporting `bundle_files 2` on 64-bit.  `bundle_files 1` ought to work as well, it was improvements to `memorymodule` for 64-bit support that addressed the issue, I just haven't tested it personally.

Comment: @Iguananaut - No worries, I wasn't aware the py2exe site was having trouble again.  My SVN Checkout from sourceforge for py2exe is rock solid though.

Comment: Can you post the code that uses Tkinter to create the GUI?

Comment: Hi.<br/>   `class GUILynCaps(Tk):
    def __init__(self, master=None):  
  Tk.__init__(self,master)
  self.queueBar = Queue.Queue()
  self.queueMess = Queue.Queue()
  self.barStted = FALSE
  self.setFrameAttrib()
  self.createWidgets()` Those methods set the widgets and properties of the app's  window

Comment: @martineau. Nop, I see the bin and dist folders generated after all process... and I'm working in a Win-7 32 bits machine

Answer (score 3):

go to cmd and type

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

wait until it finishes, and then, run

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

on cmd. A GUI should appear. Follow the instructions given.

Answer (score 0):

All credits to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZSZHmWSOeM

If you are unable to run the pip command, follow this guide:

1. Download this zip: https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe
2. Extarct the zip file.
3. In the cmd, browse to the main folder of the program, in my case C:\Program Files\auto py to exe:

   > cd C:\Program Files\auto py to exe
4. Install the repository using this command (continue in the cmd):

   > pip install -r requirements.txt
5. When finished, run the run.py file from the same folder or just type in the cmd: (Tip: Create a shortcut for this file to the desktop for future usage!)

   > python run.py

An "Auto Py To Exe" GUI should appear in the screen.

6. Select your .py file or paste the path on "Script Location"
7. Select One File mode.
8. If you are using a GUI like Tkinter, select "Window Based (Hide the console)". If not, select "Console Based"
9. Select an icon if you want and select additional files if the code has external files.
10. In "Advanced", select the output folder.
11. Click on the "CONVERT .PY TO .EXE" BUTTON. When the process has finished, you'll have a .exe file in your output folder. Execute-it. It should work exactly as the .py other.